# Get a typing effect in a Google Doc via script?

Tags: script, google-drive

Not totally sure if this is the right SE site for the question, but here goes.

I want to have a publicly viewable Google Doc which is modified programmatically (a script somewhere) and others viewing the document during the modifications are able to see the changes coming in as though another user were typing. I'm currently not clear if this is possible--so far I've been able to use the drive API to create and modify a document programmatically, but the changes only show up for each client on page refresh.

Looking over docs for the Realtime API, it's clearly aimed at doing this outside of Drive/Google Docs, which is not what I'm looking for.

One possibility is might even be some method of "typing" into an open doc via some screen scripter, though it would have to have a quick learning curve and be open source...

Hope this is clear enough, let me know if I can expand on any points. Oh, and I'm on OS X whatever the latest, and can set up a linux server if that happens to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider a keystroke emulator in your situation. Seems straightforward enough.